# Lockdown unsecure port with firewall-cmd

Tags: redhat, firewall-cmd

I have a RedHat 7 server where we allow a few ports but one of them is insecure I would like to use firewall-cmd to lock that port down to only allow 5 IPs to access it. Do I need to make a new zone for just that port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must sure you can access , via another way in case you do a mistake .

Add you 5 fives rules

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="AA.BB.CCC.DDD/32" service name="ssh" log prefix="ssh" level="info" accept'
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="AA.BB.CCC.DDD/32" service name="ssh" log prefix="ssh" level="info" accept'
```

after

```
firewall-cmd --complete-reload
```

check

```
firewall-cmd --list-all-zones
```

remove access to port 22 , and service ssh

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --remove-port=22/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --remove-service=ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly: You make a new zone for *the source IP addresses*. Then you allow that port in the new zone.